# AngularJS - passing selected item data to an edit form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I'm doing an add/edit form in angularJS.
I have a template to display the list of items and another one which contains a form. If I want to add an item then it works but I'm having issues with updating items.
This are the routes I declared, using one controller to handle everything about categories.

```
$routeProvider.when('/category', {templateUrl:'templates/category.html', controller: 'categoryCtrl'});
$routeProvider.when('/category/:categoryId?', {templateUrl:'templates/editcategory.html', controller:'categoryCtrl'});
```

In my category.html template I have a button to add(which redirects to the edit template).

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createCategory()">Add Category</button>
```

A button to edit: one button for every item.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="editCategory(category)">Edit</button>
```

This is the editCategory.html template used to add/edit.

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="categoryForm" name="categoryForm" ng-controller="categoryCtrl" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="category.name" class="form-control" required></input>
            <span ng-show="form.name.$dirty && form.name.$error.required">Category name is required</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="addCategory(category)" 
            ng-disabled="categoryForm.$invalid">Create Category</button>
            <button type="btn" value="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancelBtn()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

And my categoryCtrl :

```
myApp.controller('categoryCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.title ="Categories";
    $scope.categories = [];


    $scope.addCategory = function(category){
        $http.post('http://localhost/myappi/API/index.php/Api/categories',category).
                success(function(data) {
                    $scope.categories.push(data);
                })
                .error(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
                $location.path('/category');

    };
    $scope.editCategory = function(categoryData)
    {
        var id = categoryData.id;
        $scope.category = {};
        $scope.category = categoryData;
        console.log('scope data is ', $scope.category);
        $location.path('/category/'+id);
    };

    //go to the form to add a new category
    $scope.createCategory = function() {
        $location.path('/category/'+'new');
    };
});
```

I thought that setting $scope.category = category would also populate the form fields with the value.
Also is it a good that I used same route and template for both add/edit ?

Comment: What is the issue ? You are going right...

Comment: You are doing it right, i would suggest to move to $stateProvider if you can...

Comment: When I click on edit : the router changes from ../category to ../category/10 for example  and it goes to the editCategory.html template but the form fields are empty.

Comment: Ooh boy! You are not keeping data anywhere.. Either use service or make an http request to get the data of that `id`

Comment: @RayonDabre A console.log($scope.category)  after I assigned categoryData to it shows Object { id: "5", name: "Business", $$hashKey: "object:5" }

Comment: But when you redirect the user, you lose the data..

Answer (score 0):

Simply put when the route changes the category controller is re-initialized and so is its $scope. Consider persisting the data in a factory or a service. http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/03/communicate-with-controllers-in-angular.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use $broadcast service and pass object in it or use a custom service to persist data.

Using Custom service for persisting data is highly unrecommended as the service variables loose their values if page get refreshed so using custom service for maintaining state is highly unreliable. To pass data between different controllers, use $broadcast instead. For example, you can broadcast event from a controller in following way:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("editItem",{"category": yourValue});
```

and in other controller, you can catch this even in following way:

```
$scope.$on("editItem", function(event, args) {
  console.log(args.category);
})
```